# Using multiple SMTP addresses in youtrack

Tags: smtp, youtrack

I am trying to set up a helpdesk on youtrack, but i am experiencing issues with replying to threads.

My current set up is: Mailbox hosted on Google Apps, with multiple aliases. (lets say Test, Build, Generic)

and SMTP on sendgrid.

It is set up so that the default sending address is generic@domain.com

The problem starts when emailing Test@domain.com. The mail gets sent, received, fetched by youtrack and added as an issue. The problem is that it replies as generic@domain.com instead of replying as test@domain.com

How do i set it up so that it sends the mail from the address that it was sent to? Do i need to set up seperate mailboxes?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, email address of your mailbox with which YouTrack is integrated and 'From' email address should be the same.
You may set target Email 'From' address under Administration> Settings> Email area or, for per-project matter, under Administration> Projects> your project> Project 'From' email.
Configuring multiple SMTP addresses are not available in YouTrack at the moment. 
In general, it's better to have a mailbox per project. If you have several alases for your mailbox and integrate it with the only project process will be broken, because in Project 'From' address you'd mention only one address.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello, I've got a different problem: 3 projects, one mailbox per project, say ProjectA, projectB, and ProjectC.
When I comment an issue of projectX@mydomain.com, youtrack sends and email from globalFromAddress@mydomain.com.
If the user replies, the email goes to globalFromAddress@... which may be one of projectX@..., but will be wrong in two out of 3 cases.
Is it possible to customize the reply-to adress for each project?

Comment: nevermind, I've just found that under Projects -> myProject -> Edit Project there is "Project 'from' email" where I can configure it.